# Fastest way to fetch specific commit from (outdated) full clone?

Tags: git, fetch, clone

I have a full clone of a repo, which is slightly outdated.

```
# A few days ago:
git clone url/foo.git
```

Now I'd like to fetch and checkout a new commit which is not part of the cloned repository yet.

I can do:

```
git fetch && git checkout 409b7405
```

I assume running this will be faster as it downloads less data:

```
git fetch 409b7405 && git checkout 409b7405
```

Will it be even faster when fetching with `--depth=1`?

```
git fetch --depth=1 409b7405 && git checkout 409b7405
```

*Notes:*

- The use case is running something on a temporary cloud server instance, so everything will be deleted after running the job, and no further fetches will ever happen on the repository.
- I'm really just worried about total time, so I'm wondering if `--depth=1` might need more CPU on server or client side to run, negating any network saving (in case of a fast network).

Comment: It should be `git fetch origin --depth=1 409b7405`. Some git servers don't allow to advertise a specific commit, so it could fail. Instead, you first need to find it out which ref has the commit and then use `git fetch origin <ref>` to download the commit. But this way, it's hard to know the depth.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that "faster" tends to be relative: a lot of the time spent on a `git fetch` in some repositories takes no time at all in other repositories. Using `--depth` may minimize the amount of network data transferred right now, at the expense of more data later, and so on. You'll get misleading results from certain microbenchmarks unless they match your actual use case.

Comment: @torek: The use case is running something on a temporary cloud server instance, so everything will be deleted after running the job, and no further fetches will ever happen on the repository, added a note...

Comment: OK. I'd have to experiment, but I suspect that `--depth=1` stops the *enumeration* on the sender's side too, in which case you'll get every object (git-ified tree and blob) called for by the commit, even if those are duplicates of objects you already have. That will probably reduce CPU usage and increase network traffic for this kind of case.